# Manufacturing/Production of Spherical Lenses

Tags: optics

How are spherical lenses cut out using a diamond tip? In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6cea7dAhBc&t=4050s), the lecturer says:

> Take a piece of glass, mount it on a rotary stage. Then bring a diamond tip near the glass
> and start rotating the glass. [...] let the diamond touch the glass longer and longer as they went away from the tip of the glass. [...] you can create a spherical surface, if you move the diamond at a fixed velocity.

He means to move the diamond tip linearly.

I don't understand that explanation. Suppose the glass makes two whole rotations each second. And the diamond tip scratches out 1 unit of material in one second. Then, when the diamond tip rests for $t$ second at $x$ as in the picture, one unit of scratched out material is distributed along two full circles of radius $x$ from the center of the glass. So, the height loss is $1/(4\pi x)$. Doing the same reasoning when the diamond tip is at $2x$, as it makes two whole rotations in one second and the distance travelled at this radius is $8\pi x$, the height loss at this point is $1/(8\pi x)$.

So, when I imagine the diamond tip moving linearly from the center at zero to the outside,
the material that is scratched out is given by a function $c\cdot 1/x$ for $x > 0$ where $c = 4\pi$.
Hence, the shape is given by $h - c\cdot 1/x$ (where $h$ denotes the height of the glass). Below I have given an image, on the left hand side the diamond tip at a fixed position, on the right hand side the resulting shape given by the hyperbola $h - c/x$.

Can someone please explain? I seem to have misinterpreted the explanation, or I have made an error in my calculation.

[image]

Comment: but as the cutting point moves away from the centre of rotation then the cutter speed effectively increases even though the rpm is constant. consider defining the tip speed if the object was held stationary.

Comment: @SolarMike If I got you right, if the movement of the diamond tip increases, then it would even take away less material at each radius. The result would look like what I have drawn but with even steeper curvature toward zero. Makes no sense either... can you please be more specific (or give me the equations so I can try to figure it out...)

Comment: As you increase the radius, you increase the cut line ergo more material. ie length of cut. Check out how the cutting speeds are calculated for lathes etc. each metal needs its own speed...

Comment: @SolarMike Okay, I see that is what you meant with speed of the cutter, so that it takes away more material. I considered that too, as the lecturer wrote "let the diamond touch the glass longer and longer" which, I guess, has the same effect as increasing the cutter speed. But when I do this linearly, it would just take away the same amount of material laterally as it moves to the outside, resulting in a flat surface and not a sphere... Or can you be more specific what should be the speed of the cutter relative to its radial movement outwards?

Comment: see https://www.ctemag.com/news/articles/understanding-cutting-equations then you could check out what speeds apply to glass and the feedrates etc

Comment: @SolarMike At least now I know the technical terms (I am not an engineer to be clear). But still I am not sure what are the values to get a sphere...

Comment: So define how you need to move the point of the cutter in two dimensions to get the shape you need.